# Check a few $_GET variables in empty redirect

Tags: php

How do I check multiple variables to see if they're empty, and forward the request to a new URL if they are both empty?

Here's my code so far:

```
<?php
if(empty($_GET['Email'] and $_GET['Phone+Number'])) 
{ 
    header('Location: /index.html');
    exit; 
}
?>
```

My URL looks liks this:

```
localhost/site/success.php?Email=joe%40sample.com&Phone+Number=123456789
```

Comment: You can make a function to check that and give a list of all names as argument to that function

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure if empty is the function you can use.

**The following values are considered empty.**

1. "" (an empty string)
2. 0 (0 as an integer)
3. "0" (0 as a string)
4. NULL
5. FALSE
6. array() (an empty array)
7. var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

Code to check

```
$result = true; //assume it's all correct.
foreach($_GET as $value) {
   $result = ($result && (!empty($value))); //if it's empty, I will be false. False & anything is always false. 
}

if($result) //everything is ok
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a small function that can check this.

```
function check_empty_fields(array $fields) {

    $empty = false;

    foreach($fields as $field) {

        if(empty($field)) {
            $empty = true;
            break;  // Break as soon as the condition is reached.
        }

    }

    return $empty;

}
```

To use this function simple provide it with the fields to check. I have used the PHP function `filter_input` as a good practice to provide a minimum of input escaping.

[filter_input documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

```
$fields = [
    'email' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'Email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), 
    'phone' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'PhoneNumber', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
];
```

Now you can check the fields

```
if(!check_empty_fields($fields)) {

    /*
    * Set the HTTP status code: 307 in indicate it is a temporary redirect.
    * Use code: 301 for a permanent redirect.
    */
    header("Location: http://google.com", true, 307);

    // Remove this exit if there is anything to be done before a redirect happens.
    exit;

}
```

Comment: I have tried this method just now and nothing happens when in the URL it says localhost/site/success.php?Email=&Phone+Number=123456789

Comment: I think it is because the URL says `&Phone+Number`. This means Phone and Number is separated by a space. Try removing it in the HTML. I dont know how PHP would otherwise handle it.